# list all pip python package at url

Tags: python, pip

I am installing a package using

```
pip install --isolated --user --extra-index-url URL
```

I cant install the desired package due to version conflicts. It is a non-official package so I may be making mistakes in typing.

How can I force the URL to return a full list of available packages?

Comment: `requests.get` on the index url?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [`pip search`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_search/?highlight=pip%20search)

> ```
> python -m pip search [options] <query>
> ```
>
> Search for PyPI packages whose name or summary contains .
>
> **Options**
>
> *-i, --index*
>
> ```
> Base URL of Python Package Index (default https://pypi.org/pypi)
> ```

So basically

```
python -m pip search your_url <query>
```

Comment: I get ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500]
RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.

Comment: did you use your url, it looks like you pip search the official PyPI